How do I check if 24h have elapsed in SQL Server? I have 2 columns for the Start and 2 for the End
I need to get if the elapsed time is more than 24 hours. We can not change the table's design.
For context the table looks something like this



Start_Date
Start_Time
End_Date
End_Time




2024-01-01 00:00:00.000
2000-01-01 07:05:00.000
2024-01-01 00:00:00.000
2000-01-01 23:00:00.000


2024-01-07 00:00:00.000
2000-01-01 13:00:00.000
2024-01-08 00:00:00.000
2000-01-01 07:30:00.000



The date with fixed time and the time with fixed date. (Not my idea, just working with what I have)
The code was
DATEDIFF(HH,Start_Time, End_Time) >= 24

that obviously doesn't work.
I need some WHERE statement to filter only the entries with 24h elapsed time

Something like where enddate - startdate >= 2 or (enddate - startdate = 1 and endtime > starttime)

Fix the bad types and data. That's not a time at all. It doesn't matter that it's not your idea, the _Time columns don't contain time. It would make sense if it was a full Date+Time but definitely not this. The more you procrastinate, the worse things will get. The time type was added in 2008.

Using a datetime for a time really makes no sense, and makes far less sense when you actually want a date and time value. If you want a date and time then your column Start_Date should have the value 2024-01-01 07:05:00.000. If you want separate date and time values, you Start_date column should be a date and your Start_time column a time.

Side note DATEDIFF(HH,Start_Time, End_Time) doesn't tell you how many hours have passed, it tells yow how many times the hour has changed. DATEDIFF(HOUR,'20000101 00:59:59','20000102 00:00:00') with return 24, despite only 23 hours 1 second having passed.

The only way to filter is to fix the types with an expression. The same expression can be used to create an indexed computed column by the way, so you don't have to ever work with the non-time column. Since the base seems to be 2000-01-01 you can calculate the actual time with Start_Time - '20000101' if Start_Time is a datetime you can use use some quirky date arithmetic like cast(Start_Time-'20000101'as time) to get a real time and Start_Date + Start_Time - '20000101' to get the actual date+time. This works because YYYYMMDD is an unambiguous date literal

Once you get the actual times you can calculate their difference. DATEDIFF('HH' won't help as ThomA explained. SS compared to 86400 would be better (ignoring leap seconds). All this arithmetic will result in a full table scan too, as none of the indexes that may be covering the columns would help

Personally, I prefer using DATEADD: WHERE DATEADD(HOUR, 24, AnActualDateAndTimeValue) <= AnotherActualDateAndTimeValue

It would make some tiny sense if the base time was 1900-01-01, the value returned by cast(0 as datetime). In that case you could just add Start_Date + Start_Time and get a valid DateTime. That's a hack used before 2008. Using 2000-01-01 just makes things hard

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm working with legacy software from '99 that we can't edit and, until we replace it, we have to keep data with the same structure. That's why I said: "We can not change the table's design". I know it's bad design but, I don't need an opinion on that, thanks.

Legacy software from 1999 wouldn't use a future base date. I already explained what you can do, with full expressions. What SQL Server version are you using and what are the actual types? Date arithmetic doesn't work with datetime2 and I haven't worked with smalldatetime ... probably ever. The software's age doesn't affect how the database works either. The database version determines what works or doesn't, what types are available.

@ThomA Thanks! I was able to get an actual date like Start_Date + CAST(Start_Time as TIME). I will try it with DATEADD as you suggested! Thanks a lot.

So you're on SQL Server 2008 or later, and time is available?

@PanagiotisKanavos No, it's not using future base date. It's using 12/30/1899. I don't why, but there it is. It's using SQL Server 15.0.200 and all the columns named above are DATETIME

"It's using SQL Server 15.0.200" Do you mean 15.0.2000.5? That's the RTM version of SQL Server 2019; you're missing almost 5 years of security updates and bug fixes (which there are many of for the latter). You really need to install some updates.

You posted 2000-01-01 23:00:00.000 not 1899-12-30, which is the base date used by old versions Excel, not SQL Server. For software built in 1999 2000-01-01 is in the future. Either you posted the wrong data or the actual base date changes. You left a lot of critical information out of the question. It's also clear you're importing data from Excel. You could fix the problem at the time of import, or you can create and index computed columns that provide either actual datatimes or differences. You can even run Python scripts internally to process and possibly fix the data

@PanagiotisKanavos The data is inserted from the old software with that fixed date. I wrote that base date because I thought it didn't matter. We can't change the data in the database or the way is "meant to be" (base date for example). The old software expects that date to be there. I know it is very old but as for right now, I can't update. Thank you both, I will post my solution shortly.

The actual values always matter. If 1900-01-01 was used as the base date you could just add the two columns Start_Date + Start_Time. The legacy datetime stores dates internally as decimals, in the same format as Excel. Instead of 1899-12-30 though, it uses 1900-01-01 as the base date. That means a time of 14:34 is stored as 0.xxx and represents 1900-01-01 14:34. One of datetime's quirks is that it behaves like a decimal in arithmetic.

There are several comics related to this question. Historical Dates about the messed up dates, the Microsoft Org Chart explains how Excel, SQL Server (and probably VB6) used the same date format with different base dates.

Thnaks to Thom A suggestions for the DATEADD:
WHERE DATEADD(HOUR, 24, (Start_Date + CAST(Start_Time as TIME))) <= (End_Date + CAST(End_Time as TIME))

Using the date and adding the time cast as time got me the datetime value I needed to compare.

Your original question was to detect if MORE than 24h has transpired, right? Your answer seems to detect if WHERE ... <= ... 24h has transpired. If that's right, consider changing the code in your answer to match the question.
Additionally, after you DATEADD time to dates, your original DATEDIFF idea should work just fine.

@coge.soft I don't know what you mean. If the start time + 24h is still lower than the end it means that 24h, at least, have elapsed. Right?

May want to create scalar functions to do the conversion.
set dateformat ymd ;
--create some test data
declare @dates table
    (
     [Start_Date] datetime not null
    ,[Start_Time] datetime not null
    ,[End_Date] datetime not null
    ,[End_Time] datetime not null
    )
;
insert @dates 
    (
     [Start_Date] 
    ,[Start_Time] 
    ,[End_Date] 
    ,[End_Time] 
    )
select
     '2024-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    ,'2000-01-01 07:05:00.000'
    ,'2024-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    ,'2000-01-01 23:00:00.000'
union all
select
     '2024-01-07 00:00:00.000'
    ,'2000-01-01 13:00:00.000'
    ,'2024-01-08 00:00:00.000'
    ,'2000-01-01 07:30:00.000'
union all
select
     '2024-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    ,'2000-01-01 07:05:00.000'
    ,'2024-01-02 00:00:00.000'
    ,'2000-01-01 07:06:00.000'
;
select 
     cast(concat(cast([Start_Date] as date),' ',cast([Start_Time] as time)) as datetime2(0)) [startDateTime] --concat time [Start_Date] (take date) & [Start_Time] (take time)
    ,cast(concat(cast([End_Date] as date),' ',cast([End_Time] as time)) as datetime2(0)) [endDateTime]--concat time [End_Date] (take date)  & [End_Time]    (take time)      
    ,datediff --display different between the above in hours
        (
         hour
        ,cast(concat(cast([Start_Date] as date),' ',cast([Start_Time] as time)) as datetime2(0))
        ,cast(concat(cast([End_Date] as date),' ',cast([End_Time] as time)) as datetime2(0))
        ) [diffInHrs] 
from 
    @dates
where
    datediff --filter by is different equal or greater than 24 hours
        (
         hour
        ,cast(concat(cast([Start_Date] as date),' ',cast([Start_Time] as time)) as datetime2(0))
        ,cast(concat(cast([End_Date] as date),' ',cast([End_Time] as time)) as datetime2(0))
        )
    >= 24
;   

enter code here


This answer seems incomplete

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
